# Pullbacks of smooth densities through smooth functions are smooth?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

### Problem Statement

This is an in-text exercise from John Lee's Smooth Manifolds book chapter
14.

If $F: M \rightarrow N$ is a smooth function from manifolds $M$ to $N$, and
$\mu$ is a smooth
density on $N$, I want to show that $F^*\mu$ is a smooth density on $M$.

I can show it's a density on $M$. There's already a question that deals
with part of that
[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/623511/pullback-of-density).
If I assume that $F$ is a local diffeomorphism, I can prove the statement.
I've seen the problem stated with just smoothness in another textbook, so I
feel like it should be possible without assuming $F$ is a local
diffeomorphism.

### Attempt

I've already shown:

- If $f$ is a smooth function on $N$ and $\mu$ is a density,
  $F^*(f\mu) = (f \circ F)F^*\mu.$
- If $w$ is an n-form on $N$, then $F^*|w| = |F^*w|$.

Write $m$ = dim $M$ and $n$ = dim $N$.

Pick a point $p$ in $M$. Find a neighborhood, $V$, of $F(p)$ where we have a
non-vanishing n-form, $w$ ($w$ is a local frame over $V$ for $\Lambda^n(N)$,
the
n-forms on $N$). Using the fact that $F$ is smooth, we can find a
neighborhood $U$
of $p$ where $F(U) \subset V$. Shrinking $U$ if necessary, we have a
non-vanishing m-form on $U$, $w'$.

If I show $(F|_U)^*\mu|_V$ is smooth, then since
$(F|_U)^*\mu|_V = (F^*\mu)|_U$, I'll have shown the density is locally
smooth, and since smoothness is a local property, it's globally smooth.

Below I'll just write $F$ for $F|_U$.

Since $|w|$ is a local frame for the density bundle on $N$, for some smooth
function $f: V \rightarrow R$, we have,
$$\mu = f|w|$$

Now use our two results above:
$$F^*\mu = F^*(f|w|) = (f \circ F)F^*|w| = (f \circ F)|F^*w|$$

We also have, since $w'$ is a frame for the m-forms bundle on $M$,
$$F^*w = gw'$$
where $g : U \rightarrow R$, is a smooth function.

We then have
$|F^*w| = |gw'|$, and you can check that that's also $|g||w'|$ by evaluating on a local frame of $U$ in the tangent bundle. We then have:
$$|F^*w| = |g| |w'|$$

Because $|w'|$ is a local frame on $U$ for the density bundle, $|g|$ is the
component function of
$|F^*w|$
in that frame, so $|F^*w|$ is smooth iff $|g|$ is smooth as a function. So
here's where I have to assume $F$ is a local diffeomorphism.

If $F$ is a local diffeomorphism, then $F^*w$ is non-vanishing, so $|F^*w|$
is
a
positive density, making $|g|$ non-vanishing on $U$, so $g$ is either always
positive or always negative. Since absolute value is smooth away from zero,
$|g|$ is smooth.

Once you have that $|F^*w|$ is smooth, just note that $f \circ F$ is smooth
so
the
product is smooth.

Does anybody see some way to tweak that to work with just smoothness of $F$,
or did I go wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aack! That statement is wrong. I've posted a correction on [my web page](http://www.math.washington.edu/~lee/Books/ISM/).

Good catch!